# How to overwrite the default options of lazyvim?

Tags: editor, neovim

I want to set `vim.opt.tapstop = 4`, which is 2 in the default options.

I have written `vim.opt.tapstop = 4` in `~/.config/nvim/lua/config/options.lua`, but it didn't make any sense. On the other hand, options which are not provided by default options of lazyvim can be set normally. It is possible that the lazyvim load my `options.lua` before its default options.

I edited the `~/.local/share/nvim/lazy/LazyVim/lua/lazyvim/config/options.lua`, but it doesn't make sense as well. And the vim didn't use space instead of tabs, even though the default option is `opt.extandtab = true`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related, but maybe? I'm seeing that files in `./config/nvim/ftdetect/` are no longer sourced (I think the docs state this too) and my language-specific settings are gone. I could surely make autocmds, but it seems like I shouldn't have to do that...

Comment: Do you have a .editorconfig file? Neovim supports EditorConfig and will overwrite these settings when a .editorconfig file is found.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the option is *tabstop* rather than 'tapstop'.

Answer (score 0):

the actual default config is
`opt.tabstop = 2 -- Number of spaces tabs count for`
yo should use `vim.opt.tabstop = 4` without any trouble.